# Spring Sleuth trace IDs are gone in Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-cloud-sleuth

I've got a very simple spring cloud gateway application (nothing custom, directly download from start.spring.io, just select gateway and sleuth). To enable access logs, I have to set the system property `reactor.netty.http.server.accessLogEnabled`:

```kotlin
@SpringBootApplication
class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    System.setProperty(ReactorNetty.ACCESS_LOG_ENABLED, "true")
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}
```

And everything works just fine:

```
...
2021-12-27 17:19:05.245  INFO [gateway,,] 62156 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port 8080
2021-12-27 17:19:05.284  INFO [gateway,,] 62156 --- [           main] com.example.demo.ApplicationKt           : Started ApplicationKt in 1.855 seconds (JVM running for 2.262)
2021-12-27 17:19:09.914  INFO [gateway,e075b59a8a4bca5d,e075b59a8a4bca5d] 62156 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLog      : 127.0.0.1 - - [27/Dec/2021:17:19:09 +0100] "GET /get HTTP/1.1" 404 132 111
```

Now when I add a routing to the application:

```kotlin
@SpringBootApplication
class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    System.setProperty(ReactorNetty.ACCESS_LOG_ENABLED, "true")
    runApplication<Application>(*args) {
        addInitializers(
            beans {
                bean {
                    ref<RouteLocatorBuilder>().routes {
                        route {
                            path("/*")
                            uri("https://httpbin.org")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

The tracing information is gone:

```
2021-12-27 17:23:48.010  INFO [gateway,,] 62423 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port 8080
2021-12-27 17:23:48.042  INFO [gateway,,] 62423 --- [           main] com.example.demo.ApplicationKt           : Started ApplicationKt in 1.774 seconds (JVM running for 2.145)
2021-12-27 17:24:21.864  INFO [gateway,,] 62423 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLog      : 127.0.0.1 - - [27/Dec/2021:17:24:20 +0100] "GET /get HTTP/1.1" 200 613 949
```

It also happens with routes defined in `application.xml`.
What am I missing? Do I need to do anything while configuring routes?

Answer (score 1):

They did some changes with spring boot 2.4. Check the release notes here - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Sleuth-3.0-Migration-Guide#spring-cloud-gateway-manual-reactor-tracing-instrumentation